# How to resize Text Field using media queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

The responsive contact form is working properly for `textarea` but not for `input type=text` fields on smaller screens. I tried adding media queries.

Here is my code:

```
            <!doctype html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title></title>
            <style>
            .contact-form {
                line-height: 1.4;
                width: 50%;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
            .form-group {
                background: #F6DDCE;
                margin-bottom: 1em;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            .form-group ul {
                list-style: none;
                margin: 0 0 2em;
                padding: 0;
            }
            .form-group li {
                margin-bottom: 0.5em;
            }
            .form-group h3 {
                margin-bottom: 1em;
            }
            .form-fields input[type="text"],
            .form-fields input[type="email"]{
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 0.6em 0.8em;
            color: #999;
            background: #f7f7f7;
            border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            white-space: nowrap;
            font-size: 0.9em;
            text-decoration: none;
            line-height: normal;
            max-height: 3em;
            }
            .form-fields input[type="text"]:focus,
            .form-fields input[type="email"]:focus,
            .form-fields textarea:focus {
            color: #333;
            border: 1px solid #C17CCF;
            outline: none;
            background: #f2f2f2;
            }
            .form-fields textarea {
                display: block;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                font: 0.9em Lato, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                width: 100%;
                height: 6em;
                overflow: auto;
                padding: 0.6em 0.8em;
                color: #999;
                background: #f7f7f7;
                border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
                line-height: normal;
            }
            .form-fields label{
                text-align: left;
            }
            .send-btn {
                border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
                box-sizing: content-box;
                background: #8B798C;
                font-weight: 300;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                color: white;
                padding: 0.35em 0.75em;
                border: none;
                font-size: 1.1em;
                text-decoration: none;
                cursor: pointer;    
            }
            .send-btn:hover, .send-btn:focus {
                background: #C17CCF;
            }
            /*flex it*/
            .send-form {
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                }
            .form-group {
                flex: 1 0 300px;
            }
            .form-submit {
                flex: 0 0 100%;
            }
            .form-fields li {
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
            }
            .form-fields input[type="text"],
            .form-fields input[type="email"]{
                flex: 1 0 230px;
            }
            .form-fields label {
                flex: 1 0 90px;
                }


            /* Adding media queries*/

            @media (max-width: 400px) {
            body {
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0 0 2em;
            }
            header, .form-submit {
                padding: 2% 5%;
            }
            }
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            <header>
            </header>
            <form class="contact-form">
            <section class="form-group">
            <h3>Contact Us</h3>
            <ul class="form-fields">
            <li><label for="name">Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="your full name" class="text-input"></li>
            <li><label for="subject">Subject:</label> <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="subject" class="text-input"></li>
            <li><label for="email">Email:</label> <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="confirmation email" class="text-input"></li>
            <li><label for="comments">Comments:</label><textarea id="comments" name="comments" class="text-area">comments</textarea> </li>
            </ul>
            </section>
            <section class="form-submit">
            <button type="submit" class="send-btn">Send</button>
            </section>
            </form>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because of the flex property `flex: 1 0 230px;` for input fields. Override it with `max-width: 100%;` in media query breakpoints.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o8x85tnj/3/):

```
.form-fields input[type="text"],
.form-fields input[type="email"] {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I was earlier adding the above code but the breakpoint was 400px. So it was not working. The same set of code is working with 768px.  It means, it is very important to set correct breakpoints. Thanks a lot....

Comment: @AakrishaAgarwal Pls accept it as answer if it helps you.